# iOS Mobile Safari Virtual keyboard bug

Tags: html, ios, css, web, safari

i got some problem with iOS mobile Safari virtual keyboard.
After focusing input white space appears between fixed footer and virtual keyboard, can't figure out how to fix it.
https://youtu.be/AUqeg98AoKE

http://tokarskyi.ho.ua/testdrop2.html - link from video, you can test it, on iPhone 6/6s 5/5s Safari only vertical view.

Comment: Have something similar here. Any solution yet ?

Comment: @SergeyKhmelevskoy , Hello, unfortunately no.